# configure fails with "C compiler cannot create executables"

Tags: gcc, mingw, protocol-buffers

Right now I'm trying to compile the google protocol buffers from source with MinGW but when I try:

```
Matthew@RaRemoz-8 /e/workspace/protobuf-2.5.0
$ ./configure
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking build system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking host system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking target system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc

checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/e/workspace/protobuf-2.5.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

and the config says: [This](http://pastebin.com/WKrCqLwk)

it seems to fail around this

```
configure:3474: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3496: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
gcc.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
configure:3500: $? = 1
configure:3538: result: no
```

heres the output of -v:

```
$ gcc -v helloworld.c
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=E:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --build=m
ingw32 --without-pic --enable-shared --enable-static --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto
--enable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++
,ada --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-win32-registry --enable-l
ibstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gmp=/usr/src/pkg/gm
p-5.1.2-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpc=/usr/src/pkg/mpc-1.0.1-1-mingw32-src/bld --
with-mpfr= --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as --enable-decimal-float=yes --enable-
libgomp --enable-threads --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw32 --with-libintl-prefix=/
mingw --disable-bootstrap LDFLAGS=-s CFLAGS=-D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 cc1 -quiet -v -iprefix E:\MinGWmingw32/4.8.1/ helloworld.c -quiet -dumpbase hel
loworld.c -mtune=generic -march=pentiumpro -auxbase helloworld -version -o C:\Us
ers\Matthew\AppData\Local\Temp\ccVVxhTh.s
gcc.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

anyone encountered this or can help with this?

Comment: If you type `gcc conftest.c` at the prompt do you get the same error or something else? The output of `gcc -v conftest.c` might also be helpful - particularly if you get the `CreateProcess` error.

Comment: conftest.c doesnt even exist..

`E:\workspace>forfiles /s /m *.c /C "cmd /c echo @path"
ERROR: Files of type "*.c" not found.`

Comment: I guess the configure script erases `conftest.c` when it's done with it - `conftest.c` is just a program that has a `main()` with nothing but a `return 0;` (you can see the contents of `conftest.c` in the `config.log` file).  You can use any "hello world" program you might have lying around.  I guess I'm just verifying that MinGW is installed properly.

Comment: yeah so gcc says file not found on helloworld.c even though its there... so you may be right, any fool proof installation methods? or is it because its on e:/  ?

Comment: I don't know - post the output of `gcc -v helloworld.c` into your question.  You might want to try a MinGW distribution from http://nuwen.net/mingw.html or http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download - I have found those to install much easier than the official MinGW distro.

Comment: sweet, added the output for you, will look at those too

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong with your MinGW install, or maybe it's just that your PATH environment variable isn't set up quite right.

- `COLLECT_GCC` indicates that `gcc` is in `E:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe`
- `COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS` indicates that `gcc` couldn't locate `cc1.exe`, so it's trying to execute it as a simple `cc1` command hoping that the system will find it by a normal PATH search. The system doesn't find it, so you get the `CreateProcess` error.  Because the `Target` that GCC is built for is `mingw32`, I'd expect that `cc1.exe` would be located in `E:\MinGW\libexec\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\cc1.exe`.

There's something else interesting about the `cc1` invocation: it specifies the option `-iprefix E:\MinGWmingw32/4.8.1/`.

I'd expect it to look like: `-iprefix E:\MinGW\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/`

Something is munging the `-iprefix` option, but I'm not sure what.

I'd suggest reinstalling MinGW. As mentioned in one of my comments, I'd choose one of the following distributions since they've always installed in a straightforward manner for me. I can't say the same thing for the standard MinGW distribution installer, though I hear it's been greatly improved over the past few years.

- [nuwen.net's MinGW Distro](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) - note that recent versions of this are 64-bit native, so it will only run on 64-bit machines and apparently will only build 64-bit binaries (distro versions before 11.0 were 32-bit native and only built 32-bit binaries). One very nice thing about nuwen MinGW is that installation is simply unpacking the archive and setting the path appropriately. There's a `set_distro_paths.bat` that will add it to the path for you. Nuwen's distribution also includes several libraries, including Boost. Unfortunately C++11 threads don't seem to be supported just yet.
- [TDM MinGW](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download) - you have a choice of 32-bit or 64-bit versions. The 64-bit version will build either 32 or 64-bit targets. The toolchain itself is a 32-bit build, so it doesn't need a 64-bit machine to perform the compile/link steps. Use the `-m32` option to build a 32-bit target. The installer for TDM is a wizard-style installer. C++ 11 threads are supported, but Boost isn't included.